Upgrading dotnet in Visual Studio 2022 Community version
I have installed newer versions of dotnet on my Windows 11 system running Visual Studio Community 2022, but when I try to update one of my Windows Application projects from the Projects -> Options dialog the only ones that show up in the Target Framework drop down are .NET Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8. In the same drop down there is an option to install other frameworks and I have tried that. I have loaded both 6.0 and 8.0. They show up under C:\Program Files\dotnet, but do not seem to be available to my project. So, is VS Community limited in some way? I tried update the .csproj file using Notepad, but VS did not like that.
Thanks for your time.
Installed newer versions of dotnet from microsoft website.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-now-in-visual-studio/?hide_banner=true

can you confirm if .net sdk and runtime both were successfully downloaded? run these commands:
dotnet --list-sdks
dotnet --list-runtimes

Here is the results: 6.0.425 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

6.0.425 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.33 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.33 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.33 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sha

I can't seem to cut and paste very successfully, but it looks like versions 6 and 8 are there.

Visual Studio Community 2022 contains more than these two projects model:
Windows Application (.Net Framework)
and Windows Application.
It seems that your Windows Application projects are the first.
In my opinion,you can add the second model project and paste your codes from the  first model project to the second model project.

Thank for your time. I did try that. When creating a new Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) project I enter the Project name, then the Location, then the Solution name, then from the Framework drop down I only see .NET Framework 4.7.2 or .NET Framework 4.8. No 6 or 8. So, I'm still confused.

Whoa, I tried creating a Windows Forms App template and low and behold, the other Frameworks show up, but on a subsequent dialog. Now that is confusing. At least to me. I think you have answered my question. I thank you !!! Now, I will see if I get the latest C# version with it.
